# Compiler Error C2489 for PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS structure

Tags: c++, windows

I am analyzing an executable with DOS based structures and have gotten stuck here.

I'm getting this error when trying to compile a project:

> error C2489: 'target_nt_headers': initialized auto or register variable not allowed at function scope in 'naked' function

The lines giving me trouble are below:

```cpp
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER target_dos_header;

PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS target_nt_headers = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD_PTR)target_dos_header + target_dos_header->e_lfanew);
```

The structure `PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS` is in the Windows API to represent the PE header format.

The structure `PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER` is some sort of DOS mode file type checker at first look (there is no official documentation for this).

I have not encountered this error before, nor have I had much experience with the Windows API, so I'm a bit stuck right now.

Comment: Need to see a bit more context for your code. For instance is this code in a naked function as the error message says.

Comment: I put the main.cpp of the file im analyzing in paste bin. area of interest is around line 233 https://pastebin.com/YreVhDNX @john

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/rules-and-limitations-for-naked-functions?view=vs-2019 As the error says initailised auto variables are not permitted at function scope. Presumably you could just split it up `PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS target_nt_headers; target_nt_headers = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD_PTR)target_dos_header + target_dos_header->e_lfanew);`

Comment: Or just add extra `{ }` around the code and following loop so the declaration is in a nested scope, not function scope.

Comment: I see. thank you for the answer.